# Custom content in fancybox in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, fancybox

I have a page, which should contain kind of gallery, and some data when its clicked. So far i found how to display images in it, but how do i display some content there instead of images?
I have content type news, which i should display in light box

Comment: Here is another option available http://drupal.org/node/252260

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found easier way to do this. I have used colorbox module with colorbox node module. Easy setup, easy use.